# Why are question that no longer fit the faq being deleted instead of "historically locked" when they have value for many?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, locked-questions

A couple of recent blog posts pointed me to [Hidden Features of the Delphi IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102254/hidden-features-of-the-delphi-ide). This question was deleted and is now only visible to users with 10k+ reputation.

**What is the reasoning for deleting it instead of putting a historical lock on it?**

The answers are pretty valuable to anybody using the Delphi IDE, but are not available unless your reputation is so high you may not even need the answers.

Similar questions exist that have not yet been deleted. What is the risk of them being deleted instead of getting a historical lock? I would hate to see the content of those questions and answers lost to the greater part of this community.

Comment: The duplicate is discussing the exact same question you bring up here. And the duplicates it links to explain, in detail, the reasoning for such deletions.

Comment: @Oded unfortunately the reasons given there by Andrew Barber to delete rather than lock are entirely subjective... Also "the answers were mostly random junk" would be a reason to delete those answers but not the entire question.